3 tests failed when building vim from source
After a long struggle while building vim from source, I did make test and all tests passed except 3. Here is the output
-------------------------------
Executed:  6847 Tests
 Skipped:    68 Tests
  FAILED:     3 Tests



Failures: 
    Test timed out: Test_suspend() after 30 seconds
    From test_suspend.vim:
    Found errors in Test_suspend():
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_suspend[12]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>1 line 1: Pattern '[$#] $' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033[0m\\] '
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_suspend[29]..CheckSuspended[1]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>3 line 1: Pattern '[$#] $' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033[0m\\] '
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_suspend[29]..CheckSuspended[1]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>5 line 1: Pattern '[$#] $' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033[0m\\] '
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_suspend[29]..CheckSuspended[1]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>7 line 1: Pattern '[$#] $' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033[0m\\] '
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_suspend[29]..CheckSuspended[1]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>9 line 1: Pattern '[$#] $' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033[0m\\] '
    Test timed out: Test_suspend() after 30 seconds
    Test caused Vim to exit: Test_suspend()
    From test_termdebug.vim:
    Found errors in Test_termdebug_evaluate():
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_termdebug_evaluate line 22: Expected 'expr: n' but got '"n": 7'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_termdebug_evaluate line 25: Expected 'expr: argc' but got '"argc": 1'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_termdebug_evaluate line 28: Expected 'expr: isprime(n)' but got '"isprime(n)": 1'
    From test_terminal.vim:
    Found errors in Test_terminal_popup_two_windows():
    Run 1, 18:15:12 - 18:15:23 in 10.246607 seconds:
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[18]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>131 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[613]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[19]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>132 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\[  occurs 21 times]║\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e║'
    Run 2, 18:15:25 - 18:15:35 in 10.302279 seconds:
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[18]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>135 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[19]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>136 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\[  occurs 21 times]║\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e║'
    Run 3, 18:15:39 - 18:15:49 in 10.399375 seconds:
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[18]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>139 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[19]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>140 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\[  occurs 21 times]║\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e║'
    Run 4, 18:15:55 - 18:16:06 in 10.421925 seconds:
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[18]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>143 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[19]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>144 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\[  occurs 21 times]║\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e║'
    Run 5, 18:16:14 - 18:16:24 in 10.420285 seconds:
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[18]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>147 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e'
    command line..script /home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir/runtest.vim[654]..function RunTheTest[57]..Test_terminal_popup_two_windows[19]..WaitForAssert[2]..<SNR>4_WaitForCommon[11]..<lambda>148 line 1: Pattern 'echo ''test''' does not match '\[  occurs 21 times]║\\[\\033[1;32m\\]\\n\\w\\n>>>\\[\\033e║'
    Flaky test failed too often, giving up

TEST FAILURE
make[1]: *** [Makefile:53: report] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/noor/vim-9.1.0880/src/testdir'
make: *** [Makefile:2193: scripttests] Error 2


Should I care to pass this 3 tests? if so, how to do so?

This place is not officially affiliated with Vim. Use the issue tracker or the mailing list to report the problem.

At least you're warned that suspend, termdebug and popup windows may have problems. If you don't use these features or don't care, you're fine.

I would send a message to vim-dev or on the GitHub, but these look like minor failures unlikely to affect functioning to me. Anyway, I'm not convinced this is on-topic here, but I'll leave it open. Maybe someone writes a fun answer about the guts of those tests and what went wrong ;)
